# How to compile C++ program with using html tidy C++

Tags: c++, compilation, htmltidy

I installed tidy-dev from ubuntu repository, checked installation path - it's okay (/usr/include/tidy).

But I can not find a true flags to compile my c++ script with include tidy c++ wrapper tidyx.h from http://users.rcn.com/creitzel/tidy/tidyx.h

Can you help me?

My test script file named 1.cpp, tidyx.h I put near. 1.cpp content:

```
#include "tidyx.h"

int main()
{
}
```

I try it, but no-good:

```
$ gcc -I/usr/include/tidy 1.cpp -ltidy

In file included from 1.cpp:1:
tidyx.h: In constructor ‘Tidy::Source::Source()’:
tidyx.h:83: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(ulong)’ to ‘int (*)(void*)’
tidyx.h:84: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(ulong, byte)’ to ‘void (*)(void*, byte)’
tidyx.h:85: error: invalid conversion from ‘Bool (*)(ulong)’ to ‘Bool (*)(void*)’
tidyx.h:86: error: invalid conversion from ‘ulong’ to ‘void*’
tidyx.h: In constructor ‘Tidy::Sink::Sink()’:
tidyx.h:123: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(ulong, byte)’ to ‘void (*)(void*, byte)’
tidyx.h:124: error: invalid conversion from ‘ulong’ to ‘void*’
tidyx.h: In member function ‘void Tidy::Buffer::Attach(void*, uint)’:
tidyx.h:165: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘byte*’
tidyx.h:165: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void tidyBufAttach(TidyBuffer*, byte*, uint)’
tidyx.h: In member function ‘int Tidy::Document::Create()’:
tidyx.h:496: error: invalid conversion from ‘ulong’ to ‘void*’
tidyx.h:496: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void tidySetAppData(const _TidyDoc*, void*)’
tidyx.h: In member function ‘void Tidy::Document::SetAppData(ulong)’:
tidyx.h:511: error: invalid conversion from ‘ulong’ to ‘void*’
tidyx.h:511: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void tidySetAppData(const _TidyDoc*, void*)’
tidyx.h: In member function ‘ulong Tidy::Document::GetAppData()’:
tidyx.h:512: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘ulong’
```

Comment: What’s the error message? A shot in the dark would be that you forgot to link against the tidy library (you only include its headers)?

Answer (score 1):

To include a header file you need to use the `#include` preprocessor directive. It will look for the header file in compiler include paths.

If `tidyx.h` is in `/usr/include/tidy` you could put in your source file:

```
#include <tidy/tidyx.h>
```

and then compile just with `gcc script.cpp`, since `/usr/include` is most likely a default include path for your compiler.

Otherwise you could also put in your source file:

```
#include <tidyx.h>
```

And then tell GCC to look in `/usr/include/tidy`: `gcc -I/usr/include/tidy script.cpp`

At this point the header will be found. If you'll get other errors related to tidy (eg: some tidy functions are not defined) you'll need to link your binary to some library using GCC `-l` option.

---

**EDIT** after OP's massive edit.

Your problem here is that `tidyx.h` contains C++ code, and also your source file, looking to its extensions, seems to be a C++ source file. You'll need a C++ compiler in order to compile it. Use `g++` instead of `gcc`:

```
g++ script.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks, I known it. I rewrote the question.

Comment: You mean  "g++ -I/usr/include/tidy 1.cpp"  ?

Comment: @Arturgspb: see the first part of my answer about that. If you use `#include <tidy/tidyx.h>` you won't need to use GCC `-I` parameter. If you instead just `#include <tidyx.h>` you'll need to add `-I/usr/include/tidy` as parameter.

Comment: I do not understand what exactly I should write.

Comment: @Arturgspb: use the same parameters you used with `gcc`, but using `g++` command instead of it.

Comment: @peoro: If you mean execute "g++ script.cpp" that it diplayed same

Comment: @Arturgspb: in your updated question you said you used `gcc -I/usr/include/tidy 1.cpp -ltidy`. Try with ``g++ -I/usr/include/tidy 1.cpp -ltidy

Comment: @peoro I execute "g++ -I/usr/include/tidy 1.cpp -ltidy", but compiler throw the same errors.